# Export function in webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, google-api, webpack

I am using the google Maps API which requires a callback. How do I export a callback from a webpack bundle to use by an external script such as Google Maps API?

HTML (X-d out key):

```
<div id="hello"></div>
<script src="/js/map.bundle.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXX&callback=initMap"></script>
```

map.js:

```
var $ = require("jquery");
function initMap() {
    $("#hello").text("hello world");
}
```

I build the above `map.js` file into a webpack bundle called `map.bundle.js`.

Browser console error:

> Yc message : "initMap is not a function" name : "InvalidValueError"
>   stack : "Error↵    at new Yc (https://maps.googleapis.com/ma...

I also tried adding

```
module.exports = { initMap: initMap }
```

to `map.js` but that didn't help.

**EDIT**: Same question, but for using javascript functions from webpack bundles in form events:

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="sayHello(event)">
    <button type="submit">Say Hello</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function sayHello(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("hello");
    return false;
}
```

When the JS is packaged into a bundle, the "hello" is no longer printed on the console

Comment: Exported module needs to be first require into a variable and you will get an exported object, then you can call your exported functions.

`var initMapDep = require('./js/map.bundle');
 initMapDep.initMap();
`

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is [given here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34379664/google-maps-api-setting-up-callbacks-for-adding-markers-polyline)

Comment: @psycho Thanks for the suggestion but I don't see how that answers my question. My callback function does not accept a parameter.

Comment: No problem. You don't have to pass a parameter if you don't need it. Rest is the same initMap as you needed to use as a callback.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575637/how-to-use-webpack-with-google-maps-api

Comment: npm version of `google-maps` loader will automaticly fix your problems https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps

Comment: @redconservatory The solution in the linked question works for me. Do you want to write it as an answer so I can accept it, or do you want to mark the question as duplicate? I feel like it's broader than the linked question though the answer is the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your webpack file (map.bundle.js) does not generally write any of your functions or variables into the `global` (in this case, `window`) namespace.

This causes problems for libraries that need to be on the global namespace like jQuery or the google maps api.

One way to get around this is to add `initMap` to the window object

```
var $ = require("jquery");
function initMap() {
    $("#hello").text("hello world");
}
window.initMap = initMap;
```

Comment: instead of `window.foo` you can also set `global.foo`. Webpack will automatically convert this to `window` if your project is targeted for web (default). See [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node-global) or a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40416826/3423324)