# Google map is not working in my Wordpress website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-markers

```js
function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: 42.864281, lng: -85.761323};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: myLatLng,
    styles: [
     {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
     },
     {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
     },
     {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
     },
     {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
     },
     {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "color": "#bdbdbd"
      }
    ]
     },
     {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
     },
     {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
     },
     {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
     },
     {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
     },
     {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
     },
     {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
     },
     {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "color": "#dadada"
      }
    ]
     },
     {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
     },
     {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
     },
     {
    "featureType": "transit.station",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
     },
     {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "color": "#c9c9c9"
      }
    ]
     },
     {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
     "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
     }
   ]
    
        });
  
  
   var iconBase = 'http://novochirowellness.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10';
        var icons = {
          parking: {
            icon: iconBase + '/marker.png'
          }
        };
  
  
  var features = [
          {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.864967, -85.757060),
            type: 'parking'
          }
        ];
  
  
  features.forEach(function(feature) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    
            position: feature.position,
            icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: map,
   title: 'Hello World!'
          });
        });
  
  
      }
```

```css
 #map {
        height: 450px;
        width:100%;
      }
```

```html
 <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCmAJDksqECqEpbi3KNKMPkbmVBUeBqu90&callback=initMap">
</script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

I am using google map inside my wordpress website. And I created a custom google map with a marker for it. It doesn't load at all after the first time. If I update the api key then it runs just once and after I refresh the page it doesn't show again.

Console doesn't shows any error and I am unable to find the issue. Please help

Comment: The snippet in your questions tells you that your key has expired. Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560859/expiredkeymaperror-on-newly-generated-api-key

Comment: @Turnip I didn't get what you said...

Comment: Follow this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34392380/8730697 You need to have an API Google Maps Key

Comment: @Rahul Click the "Run code snippet" button. The console tells you that your key has expired.

Comment: Updated the key but doing the same in wordpress doesn't changes anything. It loaded once and then it disappeared again.

Comment: I still haven't found the issue but a workaround for future users if they're also having issues adding the custom google map in their wordpress website.

Add your google map code file on your web server and create an iframe with it and you can use it just like you wanted it.